# Find Three Identical Numbers in an Array in C with Nested Loops

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create an application in C that finds three similar elements in an array. For example, 1 2 3 4 3 5 3 and three is repeated three times using nested for loops.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're trying to say. Do you mean you want to calculate how many of each element there are in the array? Or something else?

Comment: is it homework?

Comment: Take the coding part as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more clear about your question...
This code will help you if you want to find only the first triple.
And I will refer to the above writers, if this is your HW, its only hurts you.

```
int findrpt(int* arr,int len){

    int cnt = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
         cnt = 0;
         for(j = i; j < len - i; j++)
              if(arr[j] == arr[i])
                  cnt++;
         if(cnt >= 3)
             return arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: what if there are 2 elements with freq 3, the question is unclear so its not appropriate to answer unclear question

Answer (score 0):

Why use nested loops? its basically **O(n^3)** time. Basically just sort the array in time **O(nlogn)** and find the element using single for loop. Benefit of sorting. In case you want to find all triples only then a single loop is required but if you want to check if some specific element is occurs three times, just apply binary search.

If the input elements are restricted to a smaller range like **[1,100]**, you can use a counter array of length 1000 initialized as `counter[[i]] = 0` . Now just run a single loop and increment the counter as:

```
for(i = 0 to length of input_array - 1)
{
  counter[input_array[i]]++;
}

if(counter[i] == 3)
  input_array[i] is a triplet
```

In this case you wont even require sorting. Cause the array counter will have the count of each element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go nested loops, you can make three nested loops, initialized from 0 to 2 elements of the array and check the condition. 
There are other easy ways too.

1. sort the array and check the condition
2. Count elements